# Deodexing with baksmali - missing java classes android implementation?

Tags: java, android, dalvik, smali

I'm trying to disassemble/deodex the ROM that came with my Samsung Galaxy S2 device.

I'm using baksmali, But cannot get two files to do so properly, Email.odex and MobilePrint.odex. Both of them want java classes that don't seem to be included with anything else on the ROM - javax.swing.abstracttable and java.awt.image.

Does anyone know if implementations for these classes are available for Android/DalvikVM?

Samsung must have used SOMETHING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, classes can be referenced in the dex file that just don't exist. This typically only happens on "dead" code paths that never actually get executed.

To get around this issue, baksmali has a -I option, to ignore these errors. This option should only be used if you are 100% certain that the classes really don't exist on the device. If used incorrectly, the option can possibly cause issues when using the device

Comment: It might have been the case. I've since used a .jar file made by the authors of VillainROM with empty signatures for the missing classes/methods that don't seem to be used.